# What is the simplest possible app you can build/run with dotnet core?

Tags: .net, linux, mono, .net-core

With mono, your "hello world" app can be *super* simple:

```
$ cat << EOF > hi.cs && mcs hi.cs && mono hi.exe
using System;

public class Hello{
    public static void Main(){
        Console.WriteLine("So simple!");
    }
}
EOF
```

The official [dotnet core samples](https://github.com/dotnet/core/tree/master/samples) are nowhere *near* as simple. Instead of requiring a compile file, execute file, it requires:

- project metadata, in the form of a `project.json` file
- running `dotnet restore` *then* `dotnet build`
- the output, which is not just a single .exe

My understanding is that `dotnet core` is supposed to be .NET for Linux and is maybe trying to pull Mono in. Is that a correct assumption? If so, *is* there a simpler hello world application that one can make with dotnet core (or something else from dotnet whatever), or is the sample project, with the several commands and multi-file output the simplest that dotnet can offer?

Comment: Is `dotnet new && dotnet restore && dotnet run` really that complicated?

Comment: `restore` took 30s when I created my example. Also, I'm not sure what it's even doing, which worries me. I don't like doing things that I don't understand :P `mcs <file>.cs` creating an `.exe` I understand. I may not know the details but I still get what it's doing. I don't understand the `run`, or why it's building `.pdb` files instead of `.exe`s, etc.

Comment: `dotnet restore` takes a long time the first time you run it, because it downloads and extracts packages, it should be faster the next time. What it does is that downloads NuGet packages into a cache and creates `project.lock.json`. `.pdb` files are created for normal .Net too, they contain debugging information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dotnet` is not just a compiler and a runtime, like Mono is, it's also a package manager and publishing platform. And those other parts are not meant to be optional. So the simplest reasonable source really does include `project.json` and running it requires `dotnet restore` (you don't need `dotnet build`, `dotnet run` calls that automatically).

If you really wanted to avoid using `project.json` (again, a bad idea), you would have to fight `dotnet` every step of the way, you're really not meant to do this. It would require something like this:

```
cat << EOF > Program.cs && dotnet /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.0-preview2-003121/csc.dll -nologo -r:"/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.0/System.Private.CoreLib.dll" Program.cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
EOF
cat << EOF > Program.runtimeconfig.json && dotnet Program.exe
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    }
  }
}
EOF
```

Comment: So... how did you get `Program.exe`? Is that the `csc.dll` part? Or the other? Also, am I correct that `dotnet` isn't really designed to be a replacement for Mono, or even really as an equivalent for building/running applications on Windows, right? Because it seems like it follows an entirely different paradigm from what I'm used to building .NET apps on Windows from the command line... and even from Visual Studio. It actually feels more to me like requiring everyone to have Visual Studio if they want to run your application...

Comment: @WayneWerner Have you ever tried to build a non-trivial .Net application without VS or msbuild? That's part of what .Net Core is trying to improve: you have just one tool, `dotnet` and you can run it from command line. .Net Core is not a direct replacement for mono, but it is the best way to run cross-platform web and console .Net applications.

Comment: Not with any dependencies, no. I think most of my confusion came from someone saying that dotnet core was supposed to be a replacement for mono, so I conflated that with "working like Mono"